# Can Ubuntu read/write to CD-RWs and DVD-RWs?

Tags: dvd, cd

The questions asks all. I searched everywhere but found nothing related to the specific topic.

I don't have problems creating a rewritable disk (assuming I already have a disk formatted as such). Just asking if Ubuntu was capable of reading and changing data stored on the disk.

Comment: The default application for burning CDs and DVDs on Ubuntu is `brasero`. You should look at its documentation for more info. But I strongly believe that there's no difference whether you burn a CD-R or CD-RW, all programs should support both. The only thing that matters is your optical drive. If it's an older one, it might not be capable of all different disk types.

Comment: @ByteCommander The problem isn't really creating a rewritable disk. Sorry if I did not mention that. I was just wondering if Ubuntu was capable of reading data on the disk as well as changing the data stored on it. Let's just assume that the disk is already formatted for rewritable use.

Comment: I did not need to try it out yet, but I would be very very surprised if that would not work. Just try it out, I'm 99% sure that if your drive supports CD-RW and DVD-RW, you can do this with Ubuntu tools just as well as with any Windows tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Linux kernel will use /dev/srX like a hard disk.
See below for DVD-RW extra needs.

But performance will be poor and probably miserable noises
will emerge when operating. The ususal hard disk writers are
not aware of the very long seek times and the quite limited
number of overwrites before a block on the medium goes bad.

Theoretically best suited would be DVD-RAM, Mount Rainier
formatted DVD+RW (MRW), and BD-RE, because they have Defect
Management, which can replace a few bad block by blocks
from the Spare Area.
In practice optical media often fail earlier with Defect
Management than without.

Capable of random read-write access are:
Formatted CD-RW, formatted DVD-RW, DVD-RAM, DVD+RW, BD-RE,
and formatted BD-R with format type Pseudo-Overwrite.

Formatted DVD-RW need the pktcdvd frontend driver which
takes care of the peculiar 32 kB granularity of the media.
This driver is recommended for CD-RW, too.
It gets set up by e.g.

pktsetup pktcdvd0 /dev/sr0

and will then be used as pseudo hard disk device

/dev/pktcdvd/pktcdvd0

See also
  http://www.g-loaded.eu/2005/11/10/packet-writing-on-cdrw-and-dvdrw-media/

Said this, please be aware that sequential writing to
optical media by a burn program is much less problematic
than random-access read-write operation.

Answer (score 0):

Long question, short answer **:)**

[image: enter your image description here]

But not in the same manner as a hard drive. For this you would need [DVD-RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-RAM).

Comment: Why does the cat look so angry ? Maybe because this didn't work ? Ha Ha Ha ... =)

Comment: @cl-netbox Alternative answer here: http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_super/5/57022/3512424-62051-grumpy-cat-yes-vnq0.jpeg